# How to use AutoMapper's ValueResolverAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have used the attribute method of mapping (introduced in AutoMapper 8.0) to do a large amount of mapping to this point. *I would prefer to keep going with the attribute method.*

However, I do not know how to implement ValueResolverAttribute given the following scenario, where I try to map a string ("*ConfigurationSetting.Key*") to an object which contains more info about the given configuration setting ("*ConfigurationSettingDTO.Key*"):

**SOURCE**

```
public class ConfigurationSetting
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**DESTINATION**

```
[AutoMap(typeof(ConfigurationSetting))]
public class ConfigurationSettingDTO
{
    [SourceMember(nameof(ConfigurationSetting.Key)), ValueResolver(typeof(ConfigurationSettingKeyResolver))]
    public ConfigurationSettingKey Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**CUSTOM VALUE RESOLVER**

```
public class ConfigurationSettingKeyResolver : IValueResolver<ConfigurationSetting, ConfigurationSettingDTO, ConfigurationSettingKey>
{
    public ConfigurationSettingKey Resolve(ConfigurationSetting source, ConfigurationSettingDTO destination, ConfigurationSettingKey key, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return ConfigurationSettingKey.GetSettingKeyById(source.Key);
    }
}
```

When implementing my attempt above, I receive the following exception during Startup:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AutoMapper.Execution.TypeMapPlanBuilder.BuildResolveCall(Expression destValueExpr, IMemberMap memberMap)
```

The AutoMapper [documentation](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Attribute-mapping.html#member-configuration) does *not* explicitly go through how to use this attribute.

---

EDIT: To be clearer, the application crashes at the first line in the following block of code in Startup.cs:

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddMaps(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()));
IMapper mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that my attribute was incorrect.

Instead of ValueResolver, I needed to use [ValueConverter](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Value-converters.html).

**DESTINATION:**

```
[AutoMap(typeof(ConfigurationSetting), ReverseMap = false)]
public class ConfigurationSettingDTO
{
    [ValueConverter(typeof(ConfigurationSettingConverter))]
    public ConfigurationSettingKey Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**CUSTOM VALUE CONVERTER:**

```
public class ConfigurationSettingConverter : IValueConverter<string, ConfigurationSettingKey>
{
    public ConfigurationSettingKey Convert(string source, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return ConfigurationSettingKey.GetSettingKeyById(source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you could use it is to use a Profile Class, I am assuming, you are working in ASP.NET Core.

Consider this:

**SOURCE:**

```
public class ConfigurationSetting
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**DESTINATION:**

```
public class ConfigurationSettingDTO
{
    public ConfigurationSettingKey Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**CUSTOME VALUE RESOLVER**

```
public class ConfigurationSettingKeyResolver : IValueResolver<ConfigurationSetting, ConfigurationSettingDTO, ConfigurationSettingKey>
{
    public ConfigurationSettingKey Resolve(ConfigurationSetting source, ConfigurationSettingDTO destination, ConfigurationSettingKey key, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // YOUR VALUE TO BE RETURNED HERE, YOU MIGHT WANT TO DOUBLE CHECK YOUR IMPLEMENTATION HERE
        return ConfigurationSettingKey.GetSettingKeyById(source.Key);
    }
}
```

Then Create a class that implements Profile like so:

**CUSTOM PROFILE CLASS**

```
public class YourCustomProfile : Profile
    {
          public GamingStandaloneProfile()
          {
               AllowNullCollections = true;
               AllowNullDestinationValues = true;

               CreateMap< ConfigurationSetting, ConfigurationSettingDTO>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.Key, opt => opt.MapFrom< ConfigurationSettingKeyResolver >());
          }
    }
```

Then in your **Startup.cs** Class do this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
          {
               ....
               services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
          }
```

This is the last line to be called in the ConfigureServices Method. I hope this helps.

Regards.